# Insert variable between ''

Tags: php, variables, mqtt

I've developed an MQTT application based on phpMQTT. It subscribes to a series of topics, on a given namespace.

I need to make the namespace variable, getting it from an ENV variable. The ENV stuff works fine. However, when I try to insert the variable in the topic in order to subscribe, it doesn't work. I am suspecting it has to do with the '' but I'm not sure.

```
//defining the variable - would be $namespace = getenv(NAMESPACE)
$namespace = "name/space";
//set the topics and subscribe
$topics['".$namespace."'/raw/#'] = array("qos"=>0, "function"=>"dostuff");
```

So how do I insert this variable as needed? Thanks.

Comment: `$topics[$namespace .'/raw/#']`

Comment: $topics[$namespace."/raw/#"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
$topics[$namespace . '/raw/#'] = array("qos"=>0, "function"=>"dostuff");
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to have done the trick - simple solutions, as always.